# Load Content in the UIWebView on the Iphone

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiwebview

I would like to show Content in the UIWebView, which I have added to the Project. (for example an image)

I know how to set a text in the UIWebView, but I would like to add images or a video which I have  added to the project.

Comment: Similar question [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501629/uiwebview-display-locally-stored-website-html-images-javascript/1501908).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I am assuming you are using *loadHTMLString* to set the HTML on your *UIWebView*.

So to reference images that are stored in your App bundle, you just need to get the right path to put in your img tag.  So get the path string:

```
NSString * imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nameOfImage ofType:@"jpg"];
```

Format some HTML with an image tag:

```
NSString * html = NSString [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\"/>", imgPath] autorelease];
```

Then set your HTML on the web view:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

You just need to add the images to your app resources (*nameOfImage* in the code above) and it will work fine.

Comment: To get the file URL, use NSURL: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:

Comment: Key phrase : "which i have added to the Project"

Answer (score 0):

Load your HTML into your UIWebView like this:

```
// assumes you have a UIWebView called 'webView', and an HTML string called 'html'
NSString* imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//", imagePath]]];
```

Then you can just refer to your images' file names:

```
<img src="your_image.png" />
```

You don't need to specify a relative path to images that you've put into folders.  When the app is compiled they all go into the root.

---

Credit: I stole this from here: http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/loading-local-files-into-uiwebview/