# UIWebView locally save images and just load html

Tags: iphone, image, uiwebview, local

i want to load just the html from the web and show the images from the local resource.

This helped me a lot, but is the path to the resource on every device the same? Or does it depend on an installation path or similar?
[Load Content in the UIWebView on the Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577576/show-content-with-uiwebview-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the path to resources is different on every device, that's why you use the function

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:nameOfImage ofType:@"jpg"]
```

the html loading from the web you can do all kinds of ways. The easiest is just:

```
NSString *myHTML = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://web.site.com/file.html"]];
```