# Unarchiving the zip file is not working

Tags: iphone, unzip, zip

i am new to iPhone programming..can anybody help me out from the following problem

i am using the fallowing code to unarcive a zip file..  its not working...  and printing the NSLog(@"Failure To Unzip Archive"); msg

```
self.fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);

self.documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/temp", self.documentsDir];

NSString *updateURL = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bmlgg.zip"];


NSLog(@"Checking update at : %@", updateURL);

NSLog(@"Checking filepath at : %@", filePath);


    ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

    if([zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:updateURL]) {

        if ([zipArchive UnzipFileTo:filePath overWrite:YES]) {
            //unzipped successfully
            NSLog(@"Archive unzip Success");
            //[self.fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failure To Unzip Archive");             
        }

    } else  {
        NSLog(@"Failure To Open Archive");
    }

    [zipArchive release];
```

thank u....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution...

the problem is the zip file is not recognized...
 i changed the fallowing code

```
NSString *updateURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bmlg" ofType:@"zip" inDirectory:@"res"];
```

[this helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501629/uiwebview-display-locally-stored-website-html-images-javascript)

```
self.fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);

self.documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/temp", self.documentsDir];

NSString *updateURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bmlg" ofType:@"zip" inDirectory:@"res"];


[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:filePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO  attributes:nil  error:nil];


       if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:updateURL]) {
        NSLog(@"File exists at path: %@", updateURL);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File does not exists at path: %@", updateURL);
    }

    NSLog(@"Checking update at : %@", updateURL); 

    NSLog(@"Checking filepath at : %@", filePath);


    ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

    if([zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:updateURL]) {

        if ([zipArchive UnzipFileTo:filePath overWrite:YES]) {
            //unzipped successfully
            NSLog(@"Archive unzip Success");
            //[self.fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failure To Unzip Archive");             
        }

    } else  {
        NSLog(@"Failure To Open Archive");
    }

    [zipArchive release];
```

Comment: i think this may not possible on the device.

Comment: i used this in may app and succesfully running on my device also

Comment: download the "ZipArchive" opensource folder, u will have minizip folder and ZipArchive files u need to import the "ZipArchive.h"